# Why is it called a "black" body?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, terminology, thermal-radiation

So I know a [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) is a perfect absorber and perfect emitter... It doesn't have to be black, but why is the term "black" used? In my textbook, it says that "at lower temperatures, a blackbody will appear black due to lower emissions" and I found on a Quora forum that at $0$  K a blackbody will be black.

Another line of reasoning I found online is that it is a "black" body because it perfectly absorbs UV light and reflects none. I don't exactly follow any of these points or understand why...

Would someone mind explaining why in fact it is called a "black" body?

Comment: @Eletie, isn't than an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine an object which is painted bright green, for example. Most of the light that shines on it which is *not* green is absorbed, and most of the light which *is* green that shines on it is reflected. This also means that it is a great emitter of green light and a poor emitter of all other colors of light.

The derivation of the blackbody radiation spectrum emitted by a hot object contains the explicit assumption that the object is equally good at both absorbing and emitting all different colors of light, which can only be true if it is actually colored black (which would be the sum of all different paint colors mixed together).

Comment: Being a poor absorber of green should not imply being a great emitter of green.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, a black body is a perfect absorber and emitter of electromagnetic radiation. As it's a perfect absorber it absorbs all visible light (a form of electromagnetic radiation). At lower temperatures it emits radiations of larger wavelengths (infrared region) because of less energy, hence appears black. At higher temperatures the wavelength of emitted radiation is in the visible spectrum hence it doesn't appear 'black'.